# Social.localUser.Image returns null in Unity3d

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, game-center

I want to access player avatar in Android and IOS, I could get userid and username using Social Class but image always returns null!!

```
if ( Social.localUser.authenticated && Social.localUser.image != null )
{
    Material m = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Transparent Colored"));
    m.mainTexture = Social.localUser.image;
    AvatarImage.material = m;
}
```

Any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Social API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.html) in Unity is only implemented for iOS.

For the Google Play Services i really recommend buying the [prime31 Google Play Game Services Plugin](https://prime31.com/docs#androidPlayGameServices) for 75$.

Alternatively there is also a Open Source [Play Games Unity Plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) from Google, but I can't recommend it, because I was not able to integrated it properly without sign in bugs.

**UPDATE 1**

The implementation for `Social.localUser.image` of the [Play Games Unity Plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) returns always null. [see PlayGamesUserProfile.cs](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesUserProfile.cs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Social class for both platforms (Ios and android), for Android I included play games plugin from google, so  far I am not having any issues while signing in either platform. The only problem is Image returns null on both platforms!

Comment: see my UPDATE 1 concerning the Play Games Unity Plugin. for iOS I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: PlayGamesLocalUser.cs This is the right script but it doesn't contain implementation of image. That script you sent doesn't contain id as well but I got that one.

Comment: yes. so to summarize: the google plugin is incomplete, so you need to add the functionality yourself or buy the prime31 plugin.

Comment: Any idea how can we add this functionality by ourselves, I have my game live and its working fine with play Games Unity plugin so I am bit hesitant moving to Prime31 plugin now

Comment: I tried adding also a missing functionality to the Play Games Unity Plugin myself but I failed and wasted almost a week of work, but at least i know the internal of that thing now :-) the big flaw and issue for me was that they spawned an extra activity for the sign in process. the move to prime31 was really smooth and so worth it

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [Google API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get) to get avatar from google for time being. From google plugin, you can create a helper function inside AndroidClient class for getting image from Android which would return you a URI.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by Tomov on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838652/social-localuser-image-is-always-returning-null/54812545#54812545) SO question worked for me with plugin version 0.10.12.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
if (Social.localUser.authenticated && Social.localUser.image != null)
                    {
                        GameObject UserAvatar = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("UserAvatar");
                        if (UserAvatar != null)
                            UserAvatar.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(Social.localUser.image, new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50), new Vector2(0, 0));
                    }
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves what the asker asked. Plain code isn't enough as an answer!