# Social.localuser.image is always returning null

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am using Unity along with the Google Play Services Plugin for Unity found over here: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

I am trying to access the players avatar to be included in a profile pic ingame. The problem is when I try accessing the Texture2D Social.localuser.image, it always returns null. Upon more research it seems that the code uses some kind of AvatarURL to find the image and that is the thing that is null. I used string.IsNullOrEmpty(AvatarURL) to check this. Does anyone know why AvatarURL is null, and/or how I can fix it. If not that, is there any alternative way to accessing the players avatar to use for a profile picture in my game.

Here is the code I used to test this:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

//Authenticate User
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
    if(success) {
        Debug.Log("Successfully Authenticated");
        Textures.profilePic = Sprite.Create(Social.localUser.image, new Rect(0, 0, Social.localUser.image.width, Social.localUser.image.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Failed to Authenticate User");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("ErrorCanNotSignIn");
    }
});
```

The error happens when setting Textures.profilePic (Textures is another class I created that stores textures, and profilePic is a static Sprite variable in it). It says there is  a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of the object.

Again based on what I've seen, I think the source of the error seems to be the AvatarURL being null, as it causes this code, which I am pretty sure is what loads the image, not to run:

```
if (!mImageLoading && mImage == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AvatarURL))
{
    Debug.Log("Starting to load image: " + AvatarURL);
    mImageLoading = true;
    PlayGamesHelperObject.RunCoroutine(LoadImage());
}
```

Also if it's important, I am testing this on an android device.

Answer (score 1):

Question answered by JeanLuc on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238474/social-localuser-image-returns-null-in-unity3d) SO question

> The implementation for Social.localUser.image of the Play Games Unity
>   Plugin returns always null.

Comment: Okay, this is a little weird but I seem to have gotten Social.localUser.image to not return null. I made it directly modify the sprite of a gameObject ingame. When I did at first, the sprite remained null and stayed completely blank, but for some reason when I switched the scene from that scene to another and then back it worked, and the player's profile pic was there

Comment: You should post this on the GitHub discussion because is very weird and needs to be solved by Google team. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It's still not exactly what I want because it only works when the player switches the scene (Main menu to settings screen) and then returns to original scene that the sprite actually changes to the person's profile pic. Do you have any idea why it could be behaving like this?

Comment: This sounds like something related to initializing the "LocalUser" I can take a look later and post my research.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the image returns null is because it's loaded asynchronously, so you'll need to wait for it.

Furthermore there's a bug where you first need to access Social.localUser.userName.

This code should be working:

```
    Debug.Log(Social.localUser.userName);   // you need to access Social.localUser.userName, otherwise the image will always return null
    StartCoroutine(KeepCheckingAvatar());
// ...

    private IEnumerator KeepCheckingAvatar()
    {
        float secondsOfTrying = 20;
        float secondsPerAttempt = 0.2f;
        while (secondsOfTrying > 0)
        {
            if (Social.localUser.image != null)
            {
                // Do something with freshly loaded image

                break;
            }

            secondsOfTrying -= secondsPerAttempt;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsPerAttempt);
        }
    }
```

Credits:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1056#issuecomment-212257972